# Changing `proof` endmark when using `ntheorem` with `thmmarks` and `amsthm` options

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

Q: Is there an easy way to change the default `proof` environment endmark (it's normally a funny open square and I'd like to change it to `\blacksquare`) when using the `ntheorem` package with the `amsthm` and `thmmarks` options? I'd like to continue using the `ntheorem` package without migrating over to `amsthm`

You can see below that I added a `\square` endmark to the different theorem environments. I'm just stuck on changing the `proof` endmark. You can see below I tried the code

`\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}`

It didn't work. A number of other approaches didn't work either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[My Theorem]
  Lorem ipsum. 
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}[My Definition]
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: endmarks]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
\renewcommand\proofSymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
```