# With ntheorem, thmmarks and no amsthm, defining the proof environment right

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

I'm using `ntheorem` with the `thmmarks` option but without the `amsthm` option (for reasons I won't go into). I would like to define the `proof` environment à la `amsthm`. Specifically, I want:

- To be able to use the proofSymbol command to affect all proofs, as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51828/5640).
- To be able to specify that, by default, proofs will have no QED symbol.
- For the proof symbol, when it appears, to appear by default at the end of the line (i.e. after an `\hfil`).

What I did was 'lift' the definition from `ntheorem.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\gdef\proofSymbol{\openbox}
\newcommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \th@nonumberplain
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont
  \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
  \@thm{proof}{proof}{#1}}%
  {\@endtheorem}
```

And add a counter definition. Here's the result in an working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\gdef\proofSymbol{\openbox}
\newcommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\newcounter{proof}\newcounter{currproofctr}\newcounter{endproofctr}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \th@nonumberplain
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont
  \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
  \@thm{proof}{proof}{#1}}%
  {\@endtheorem}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\proofSymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Without \verb|\qed| in this one.
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
With \verb|\qed| in this one. \qed
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

(**Edit:** Dropped the \lipsum 's from the MWE) What happens is that I get a black square when not specifying `\qed`, but no black square when I do specify it. So,

- How do I get `\qed` to work now?
- To avoid a symbol by default now, I'll just set `\theoremsymbol{\relax}`, right?
- Can I overcome the "no `\par` before the end" limitation?

Comment: Please post an MWE. It would be instructive to know which document class you use, and also which other packages you load. When I try to build a minimal example, I unfortunately get the error message `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'currproofctr' defined.`.

Comment: (1) why all this code? (2) why a proof env with no marker by default? Why not two different envs, cleaner interface, both can be make with approx 4 lines of code each. More if you want to lift openbox, but it is just as easy to just use square

Comment: @daleif: See edit. It's not me, it's ntheorem...  also, remember I just want to replicate amsthm's proof environment, not do anything better/smarter.

Comment: @Mico: See edit.

Comment: Then why are you using `ntheorem` and not just `amsthm`?

Comment: Try replacing `\lipsum[1]` with `\lipsum*[1]` -- the QED symbol should start showing up.

Comment: @mico yes `ntheorem` really dislikes `\par` before `\end....`

Comment: @Mico: Yeah, that helps. I wonder... never mind. Now two problems remain, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in detail: I define two different environments, `proof`(with a qed symbol) and `proof-wo` without qed symbol.

However, note it is enough to define only a proof environment (with   qed symbol by default), and add `\NoEndMark` if you do not want this symbol.

Also I do not see the  point of numbering proofs. Nevertheless, should you really want to, just change the theorem style to `plain` and replace `\newtheorem{proof-wo}{Proof}` with `\newtheorem{proof-wo}[proof]{Proof}`if you want to have only one counter for both environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
 \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
 \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
 \theoremseparator{.\,—}
 \theoremsymbol{}
 \newtheorem{proof-wo}{Proof}
 \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{lightgray}\blacksquare}}
 \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof-wo}
Without \verb|\qed| Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin
vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat
ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hen-
drerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellen-
tesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{proof-wo}

%
\begin{proof}
With \verb|\qed| Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin
vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat
ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hen-
drerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellen-
tesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{proof}
%
\begin{proof}\NoEndMark
Without \verb|\qed| Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin
vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat
ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hen-
drerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellen-
tesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment

The standard method of making an `ntheorem` `proof` env is something similar to
(untested, in a hurry)

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoresymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

I do not understand why you are using all that code.

I would then also make a variant that has an empty `\theoremsymbol` and call it say `proof*`

Remember that `ntheorem` and `amsthm` are very different beasts and the former does not support `\qed`

Comment: WHen I use your code with my body I get compilation erros. Also, remember, no `amsmath`. As for not understanding - again, tell that to the ntheorem author(s), I didn't make that stuff up.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not loading any amsthm, there is a typo, should read bodyfont

Comment: Sorry, meant no amsmath. Oh, I just noticed I had that in the title as well. I meant the amsmath option to ntheorem.

Comment: @einpoklum Just remove the option, why no amsmath? It is more or less standard

Comment: Compiling this: http://pastebin.com/LYMrQ1xf  I get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \theorembodybont
                    {\normalfont}
`. Using TeXLive on Debian Stretch.

Comment: @einpoklum read my comment above

Comment: Hmm. It looks like there's both an amsmath and amsthm option. So I had not been confused after all. But - adding amsmath doesn't seem to matter.